# Trouble finding pdfs of "Tables of Interatomic Distances and Configuration in Molecules and Ions" series books

Tags: reference-request, databases, geometry

I am currently trying to find molecular geometry data prior to 1960, and it seems like
"Tables of Interatomic Distances and Configuration in Molecules and Ions (1958). Special publication No. 11. The Chemical society, London"
and
"Tables of Interatomic Distances and Configuration in Molecules and Ions, Supplement 1956-1959 (1965). Special publication No. 18. The Chemical society, London" are 2 great sources to check out.

However, in my online searches, I can only find one or two page pdfs which include these titles in a citation, or library websites which claim have the physical copies of these books. Due to time constraints, I would prefer to have access to the online copies of these books rather than the physical volumes themselves. Has anyone found full online pdfs for these books before? Or are there more accessible alternative sources for molecular geometry data prior to 1960?

Comment: This isn't exactly the answer you are looking for, but perhaps it might be worth looking at the [Computational Chemistry Comparison and Benchmark DataBase](https://cccbdb.nist.gov) (CCCBDB)? While it _sounds_ like a computational benchmarking website, it's actually got a lot of experimental data as well, including pages specifically dedicated to diatomics (although you can also search for molecules if they're not listed there). They have references for a some of the experimental data, but none for the computational data (at least, I've not seen any so far).

Answer (score 6):

Found No. 18: https://archive.org/details/tablesofinterato0000lesu/page/n3/mode/1up (an Archive.org account is free and fairly quick to register for).

Comment: Thanks! How did you manage to find this pdf? Or is Internet archive something you go to regularly?

Comment: archive.org is a good starting point for free obscure ebooks ^_^' If you search for "Table of Interatomic Potentials" there, this is the first search result. Couldn't really find No 11 though.